# Is it necessary to publish managed package on Appexchange?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

If I am creating a managed package, is it necessary to publish it on Appexchange?

The package I have created, Is there any other way I can install the package on a salesforce instance (not my) without going via appexchange?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no necessity that if we are making a managed package then it should be on Appexhange. Appexchange is basically a marketplace for salesforce as Itunes is for Apple.

To install a package:

When create a package and upload it, after successful upload it provide installation link. It can be gone through Build | create | package and select your packages > Then select your package name > Installation URL seems like   https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t900000003mGs.

Just copy and paste that url and follow the instruction to upload.

Note: For successful package creation test class coverage must be >= 75%